# Extract substring from a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a new column in the data frame df, if the condition that the variable "product" is equal to "ADDITION" is met, then the substring "Add Task" is extracted from the variable "descrip".

This is the dataframe:

[image]

This is the code:

```
df.astype({'descrip':'str'}).dtypes

df['modif_prod']= np.where(df['product']=='ADDITIONAL',df['descrip'].str.extract('(Adic Task:\s\d{6})'),0)
```

Comment: Please post the dataframe here, not just an image of it which we can't copy-and-paste. When you try your code, what happens? Show us the output, why is it wrong?

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `expand` param and it'll work:

```py
>>> df['modif_prod']= np.where(
...     df['product']=='ADDITIONAL', 
...     df['descrip'].str.extract('(Adic Task:\s\d{6})', expand=False),
...     0
... )
```

---

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

> If True, return DataFrame with one column per capture group. If False, return a Series/Index if there is one capture group or DataFrame if there are multiple capture groups.

Since you're now returning `pd.Series`, your result could be assigned to a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can also use assign function in code chain:

```
(
     df.assign(lambda x: 
         np.where(x['product']=='ADDITIONAL', x['descrip'].str.extract('(Adic Task:\s\d{6})', expand=False),0)
     )
)
```